# Angular Jest run tests in file

Tags: angular, jestjs

I got an Angular v16 app with the newly released Jest support from Angular. When I run `ng test` it runs all the tests with Jest as expected. However, if I try to run a test suite using WebStorm UI it uses Jest CLI and tests fail, because it cannot handle `.ts` files. Are there any flags that could be passed to Jest so it could be ran using `jest` CLI? (without adding custom configs etc. just by using bare Angular's Jest integration).